# Amazon Elastic Beanstalk + Django + Sentry retornando raven.exceptions.InvalidGitRepository

Tags: django, amazon-aws

Estou tentando deploy na AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Meu projeto tem uma estrutura onde o settings do Django está na pasta settings:

```
|projeto
|--settings
|----settings.py
```

Ele contem a configuração como:

```
RAVEN_CONFIG = {
    'dsn': 'https://----------:---------@sentry.io/------',
    'release': raven.fetch_git_sha(os.path.dirname(os.pardir)),
}
```

Acredito que o erro está na linha do **release**, já mudei ela de todas as formas, tentei com 2 niveis acima, tentei de tudo e ele retorna erro de que nao identificou repositorio git (que existe).

```
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/raven/versioning.py", line 25, in fetch_git_sha
'Cannot identify HEAD for git repository at %s' % (path,))
raven.exceptions.InvalidGitRepository: Cannot identify HEAD for git repository at.
```

Por causa deste erro não consigo fazer o sentry rodar no Elastic Beanstalk. Tentei também com o modelo que eles tem no tutorial com o wsgi chamando o Sentry. Também da o mesmo erro. Provavelmente porque o config vale para qualquer método de instalação utilizado.

Comment: Você poderia adicionar mais detalhes sobre o erro, por exemplo o log? Geralmente há uma uma explicação sobre o erro.

Comment: O log é o que coloquei no proprio post. `File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/raven/versioning.py", line 25, in fetch_git_sha
'Cannot identify HEAD for git repository at %s' % (path,))
raven.exceptions.InvalidGitRepository: Cannot identify HEAD for git repository at. `

Comment: pelo q entendi ele nao conseguiu pegar o HEAD do git...mas minha pasta .git vai junto no deploy. Não entendo pq ele tem q pegar o HEAD do git pra funcionar o sentry, mas de qualquer forma deveria pegar.

Comment: Em algum lugar da configuração há espaço para configurar o local/path do projeto?
Porque ele tenta encontrar {path}/.git/HEAD e ao não encontrar, ele exibe o erro "repository at {path}", como está saíndo "repository at .", então o path atualmente é ".", o que parece ser incorreto.
https://github.com/getsentry/raven-python/blob/master/raven/versioning.py#L22

Comment: De curiosidade, algum motivo pra separar o arquivo `settings.py` dentro de outra pasta? Se mover ele pra raiz, volta a funcionar?

Comment: Tentou fazer um gitclone no repositório que você levou?Copiar e colar pode não ser o bastante.

Comment: @leonardopessoa ja movi e ainda assim nao deu certo, mas o motivo é apenas para organizar o projeto. De qualquer forma ele ja estava numa pasta que era a do próprio projeto. Mas creio que nao seja este o problema, pois a mensagem do log é relativa ao git. Porém na amazon elasticbeanstalk a pasta do repositorio nem mesmo vai para o deploy

Comment: @LeonanCarvalho nao tem sentido fazer um git clone no elastic beanstalk....o processo de deploy dele é automatizado.

Comment: @Renato eu ja vi este link que vc mandou, é a linha do codigo que ele da o erro. Eu verifiquei essa configuração, que seria a PYTHONPATH se nao me engano. O problema é que o deploy do Elastic Beanstalk nem sequer envia a pasta .git, conectei via ssh e vi as pastas que ele usa na instancia e nem existe a .git. Eu simplesmente estou desistindo do Sentry na AWS EBS e to usando o logging pra jogar os erros num db e enviar por email.

Answer (score 1):

O ElasticBeanstalk não usa `git` para fazer deploy das revisões da aplicação. Ele usa "bundles" da aplicação inteira guardados no S3 (um zip/tarball de todo o repositório, sem o `.git`).

Você precisa puxar a revisão (sha, versão etc.) de outro lugar sem ser o sha do `git`. Também pode incluir isso no bundle, antes de fazer deploy (i.e. `git rev-parse HEAD > ./git-current-head && eb deploy`), e ler no código.

Comment: Eu tentei colocar o sha do git hardcoded no Sentry e nao rolou. Essa sua solução seria adequada se funcionasse hardcoded, correto? `'release': 'qualquermerdadeshahardcoded',` ignorando esta função de **raven.fetch_git_sha** Eu não entendo porque raios o Sentry quer o sha do git...se a pasta .git nao vai junto no bundle ele vai fazer o que com esse sha? Ai minha linha do config ficaria com o sha direto? Pq no raven versioning ele exige ter uma pasta .git com o arquivo HEAD dentro.

Comment: O raven quer justamente te dar feedback sobre qual versão está rodando no seu app e dando erros. Aí ele te ajuda com esse helper pra pegar o sha do git. Mas no ElasticBeanstalk não tem git, então você precisa versionar de outro jeito; por exemplo escrevendo o sha num arquivo e usando esse valor do `'release': ...`.

Comment: No meu app (usando CodeDeploy, não EB; mas é parecido), eu faço isso. No deploy: `git rev-parse HEAD > ./git-current-head`
No código: `'release': open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__, '../git-current-head')).read().strip()`

Comment: Você pode só apagar o `release` também e vai funcionar. A única questão é que você perde essa informação útil (qual versão do app está rodando).

Comment: Aparentemente você também poderia pegar esse metadado do arquivo que o EB cria: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28488069/2648256

Comment: blz, vou testar esse método ainda hoje, se der certo os pontos serão seus :) na real acho q o q mais me ferrou foi q ele nao tava atualizando o bundle e chega até a excluir todos os arquivos da current/app, sei la porque

Comment: Eu não sei, mas imagino que se o deploy falhar ele ignore a revisão.

Os serviços de deploy automático do AWS também fazem umas coisas estranhas tipo ficar num loop tentando provisionar, falhando, destruindo a instância e subindo uma nova... etc.

Comment: Não funcionou no final?

Comment: Ainda não, eu montei um ambiente novo só pra testar e continua dando erros. Vou tentar mais essa semana.

Comment: @KarlZillner isso não funcionou?

Comment: Não. Abandonei a idéia e fiz um monitor de erros na unha.

Comment: x.x que coisa..